# How to get get ipNetToPhysicalNetAddress column from ipNetToPhysicalTable?

Tags: snmp, oid

Is it possible to get ipNetToPhysicalNetAddress column from ipNetToPhysicalTable from OID tree? In all devices that I tried I received "NoSuchInstance" SNMP error.

Thanks in advance,
Vasyl

Answer (score 0):

`ipNetToPhysicalNetAddress` is a Table entity. You can not get it directly by its OID (1.3.6.1.2.1.4.35.1.3). Append `ipNetToPhysicalEntry`to its base OID.

[Loot at this.](http://www.webnms.com/snmp/help/snmpapi/snmpv3/table_handling/snmptables_basics.html)

Thanks.